# Using JLists In Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have to work with JLists for a project and I am stuck trying to do a couple of things.
Here are my lists:

```
JList<String> BooksList = new JList<String>(booksList);
books.add(BooksList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
BooksList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);


JList cartList = new JList();
cart.add(cartList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
cartList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

In The BooksList are the following items:

```
I Did It Your Way;11.95
The History of Scotland;14.50
Learn Calculus in One Day;29.95
Feel the Stress;18.50
Great Poems;12.95
Europe on a Shoestring;10.95
The Life of Mozart;14.50
```

1.) Moving Items From BooksList to cartList, specifically I need it to append the newly added items but if I try to add items one at a time then it will replace what is already in cartList with the new item. here is the code I have:

```
//Adding To Cart
JButton AddToCart = new JButton("Add To Cart");
AddToCart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ArrayList<String> selectionList = (ArrayList<String>) BooksList.getSelectedValuesList();
        Object[] selections = selectionList.toArray();
        cartList.setListData(selections);
    }
});
AddToCart.setToolTipText("Alt + A For Auto Add");
AddToCart.setBounds(264, 178, 117, 25);
AddToCart.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
frame.getContentPane().add(AddToCart);
```

2.) Clearing The Cart List Completely, for some reason nothing happens when this clicked. here is the code:

```
//This Will Clear The Whole Cart List
JMenuItem Clear = new JMenuItem("Clear                                  Alt + C");
cartMenu.add(Clear);
Clear.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
Clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        DefaultListModel tempModel = (DefaultListModel)cartList.getModel();
        tempModel.removeAllElements();  
    }

});
```

3.) Removing Selected Items, same thing as 2 it just doesn't do anything. I have the following code:

```
//Remove A Selected Item From The List
JMenuItem RemoveSelected = new JMenuItem("Remove Selected             Alt + R");
cartMenu.add(RemoveSelected);
RemoveSelected.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
RemoveSelected.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultListModel tempModel = (DefaultListModel)cartList.getModel();
        int selected = cartList.getSelectedIndex();
        if(selected != -1)
        {
            tempModel.remove(selected);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In what way are you stuck? Are you getting an error?

Comment: For 1 I have to be able to add multiple to the cartList from the BooksList and do it one at a time, but if I try to add all the items one at a time it will erase the item in the cartList and only put the new item in
For 2 and 3 they just dont work. When the item is clicked nothing happens

Comment: Add this information to your *question* not in comments as this is key information which you left out of your question leaving it quite incomplete.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 4):

When you add to the `JList`, you want to add it to its `ListModel` rather than directly:

```
DefaultListModel tempModel = (DefaultListModel) cartList.getModel();
for (String s: BooksList.getSelectedValuesList())
    tempModel.addElement(s);
```

I haven't had a chance to test that, but that's the right approach. Currently, you're calling `.setListData()`, which clears out what's there and replaces it. This will add something to it instead.

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212983/jlist-add-remove-item) helpful.